# Creating Table in SQL2005 through .net program

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

I need to create table on the fly in C#.net program. Task is to export excel file to SQL Database. How to write store procedure for creating table if column name and table name are passed as parameters? I tried to write following SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CreateTempTable
@Param1 VarChar(50),
@Param2 VarChar(50),
@Param3 VarChar(50),
@Param4 VarChar(50)
AS
if exists(select * from sys.objects where object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Temp]') AND type='U')
begin
Drop Table [dbo].[Temp]
end

Create Table [dbo].[Temp]([@CountryID] [int],
[@Param1] [VarChar](150),
[@Param2] [DateTime],
[@Param3] [VarChar](50),
[@Param4] [VarChar](50));

RETURN
```

While executing if I give input as

```
@Param1 - 'CountryId'
@Param2 - 'CountryName'
@Param3 - 'CreateDate'
@Param4 - 'CreatedBy'
```

The column created as @Param1, @Param2, @Param3, @Param4 instead of CountryId... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of your sproc should be

```
exec ('CREATE TABLE [dbo.Temp] (' + @param1 + ' int,' + @param2 + ' [DateTime], ' + @Param3 + ' VarChar, ' + @Param4 + ' VarChar)')
```

Although, as you're calling it from .net, you might as well just build up a string in .net and execute that as inline SQL...

eg:

```
string sql = string.Format("CREATE TABLE [dbo.Temp] ({0} int, {1} [DateTime], {2} VarChar, {3} VarChar)", fieldName1, fieldName2, fieldName3, fieldName4);
```

And then just execute that as SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I used string query and is working fine. I am now able to pass any number of columns, and can even set datatype to it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx) system stored procedure with a custom string that you have to build in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like :

```
execute 'Create Table [dbo].Temp, ' +[@Param2]+' [DateTime], '+[@Param3]+' VarChar, '+[@Param4]+' VarChar);';
```